# Subtract Values in Two Ranges VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write VBA code to subtract column A from column B. I want it to take the first cell in each range and do the math then output the resulting value in column C.

i.e. the output should look like:

[image: Sample Input/Ouput]

Comment: Let's have a look at your initial VBA.

Comment: What have you done till now?

Comment: You could use this code:
Sub TheDifference()
With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Address(0, 0))
    With .Offset(0, 2)
        .Formula = "=SUM(-A1,B1)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With
    
End Sub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub FOO()
[C1:C6] = [B1:B6 - A1:A6]
End Sub
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity what object type does this use? Cells? Range?

Comment: `[C1:C6]` is short Hand for `ActiveSheet.Range("C1:C6")` and `[B1:B6 - A1:A6]` is short Hand for `ActiveSheet.Evaluate("B1:B6 - A1:A6")`